# jQuery Chained - don't work on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I'm using [this plugin](https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_chained) to get chained select's.

It's working with desktop browser (FF, Chrome, etc...) but when I want to use it on my iPhone it's not working.

I can select options from first select (for example city). When I select city, my second select should have locals from this city and that's what not working on iOS, second select is disabled all the time. I tried modify chained code and added

```
tap, touchstart
```

but it doesn't help.

```js
$("#locals").chained("#city");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/tuupola/jquery_chained/2.x/jquery.chained.js"></script>

<select id="city" name="city">
  <option value="Select city">Select city</option>
  <option value="CityA">City A</option>
  <option value="CityB">City B</option>
</select>
<select id="locals" name="locals">
  <option value="Select local">Select local</option>
  <option value="Local A" data-chained="CityA">Local A</option>
  <option value="Local A-1" data-chained="CityA">Local A-1</option>
  <option value="Local B-1" data-chained="CityB">Local B-1</option>
  <option value="Local B-2" data-chained="CityB">Local B-2</option>
  <option value="Local B-3" data-chained="CityB">Local B-3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Which iOS version ? Which browser (+version) ? Any error ?

Comment: @Serge K. ios 11.2.1, default Safari browser. I don't have any errors on dekstop (chrome console). It's looks like plugin can't "catch" my tapping on first select or something

Comment: call this method inside document ready. i.e. $(document).ready(function(){ $("#locals").chained("#city"); });

Comment: Maybe there *is* an error on your phone ?

Comment: @Ankush Jain it's strange. I called this method inside document ready but at the end. Now I move my call to the top of my code and now it's working. Thank you!

Comment: Would like to know, what other code was suppressing `.chained` in iOS?

Comment: Not working on iOS 11.2.6 neither.

Comment: @SergeK. are you also using Firebase? I have the exact problem as you on Safari, but if i comment out everything related to firebase, the chained plugin starts working again.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
    $("#locals").chained("#city");
```

please replace by

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#locals").chained("#city");
    });
```

detail please watch at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YL6BwAZnUag

Comment: it wasn't neccessary to record video for me but thanks!